# How do I create a colorstate list for both of my themes?

Tags: android, onclick, imageview, onclicklistener, tint

I am making a messaging application in Android, and I want to make an emoji keyboard. I have the layout set up and now I'm going to start coding the layout. However, my light and dark theme is conflicting with this.

The way my dark theme system works is I have an `attrs.xml` file, and this file declares all of the colors I will use for layouts, and `styles.xml` defines them for both themes, so whenever I want to use a color, I will use `?attr/iconTint` for example and then it will look correct on both themes.

Whenever someone selects a category in the emoji keyboard, it should set the color to an `attr` attribute so I can change the tint programmatically, and so that the colors will fit the currently selected theme.

The problem with this is that it isn't showing the correct color, and someone suggested that I need to use a **colorstate list**, but I don't know how.

How do I create a colorstate list that detects what theme I am in, and then sets the tints of imageviews based on the current theme?

Answer (score 0):

I've always used these methods when I want to change the color tint of the `ImageView`

```
   public static void setTintColor(ImageView img, int color) {
        ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(img, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
    }

    public static void clearTintColor(ImageView img) {
        ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(img, null);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, this has not worked for me. I put the color attribute as my `R.attr` attribute, but it still has the same colors as when I used `setColorFilter`

Comment: why you putted the color in the `attr` file? it's should be in the`color.xml` file

Comment: My dark mode system works like that. I have an `attrs.xml` file that creates all of the colors in activities, in `styles.xml` I define the colors of those attrs for light and dark theme, and whenever I want to assign a color, I just use `?attr/iconTint` for example, to set it to that color.

Comment: I'm probably going to need a different method to set the tints like that. 

Comment: It just needs to be a method to set the tints of image views with an attr attribute. Hopefully that sums it up well.